# SQL insert fails with Entity Framework Core in SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have the following insert script:

```
INSERT INTO Sections (ID, Name, Type, Notes, CodeI, CodeII, DataID, CodeIII, CodeIV, ShopID) 
VALUES ("787c4d0b-8b6e-4bed-8fb7-03932d0346cd", "Test shop", "R", NULL, "123456789", "1234", NULL, "11", "1234", NULL);
```

I use a mobile SQLite database with Entity Framework Core.

This is my executer method:

```
public async Task ExecuteCommand(FormattableString command)
{
  if (command == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(command));
  try
  {
    await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(command);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw;
  }
}
```

This is the calling code:

```
var command = $"INSERT INTO Sections (ID, Name, Type, Notes, CodeI, CodeII, DataID, CodeIII, CodeIV, ShopID) 
VALUES ('787c4d0b-8b6e-4bed-8fb7-03932d0346cd', 'Test shop', 'R', NULL, '123456789', '1234', NULL, '11', '1234', NULL);"
await ExecuteCommand(command);
```

When I execute the following:

```
 await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(command);
```

I get this exception:

```
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'near "@p0": syntax error'.
  at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC (System.Int32 rc, SQLitePCL.sqlite3 db) [0x00067] in <56cfa09aae23467e945f1a64a1f893bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand+<PrepareAndEnumerateStatements>d__62.MoveNext () [0x0008a] in <56cfa09aae23467e945f1a64a1f893bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) [0x0025d] in <56cfa09aae23467e945f1a64a1f893bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader () [0x00000] in <56cfa09aae23467e945f1a64a1f893bb>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery () [0x00042] in <56cfa09aae23467e945f1a64a1f893bb>:0 
  at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00049] in <6409c8a079bb4f4c8dff9761b9062573>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand+<ExecuteAsync>d__17.MoveNext () [0x00358] in <e12f0cc891a249419803faaf433b12e6>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions+<ExecuteSqlCommandAsync>d__13.MoveNext () [0x00154] in <e12f0cc891a249419803faaf433b12e6>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <43dbbdc147f2482093d8409abb04c233>:0 
  at MyXamarinTest.ExecuteCommand(FormattableString command)
```

What am I doing wrong when I try to insert data in my database with Entity Framework Core?

Comment: what does your table look like and was your table created with a migration?

Comment: I am alittle confused as to why you are using SQL to actually do the insert? and not using `dbContext.Sections.Add(yourObj);` with a subsequent `dbContext.SaveChanges();`

Comment: @mvermef I only have an MS-SQL insert script text file and I need to insert all the data. Creating objects makes it way too cumbersome. I created the tables with migration and I guess I know why the insert fails.

Comment: It seems you have a syntax error to first property `ID`. You need to check the type of this property.

Comment: @Nestor is ID auto inserted?

Comment: Are you sure the SQL generating the exception is the one you have shown? `near "@p0"` means the query contains parameters and the shown SQL contains just constant values. Turn [Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging) on to see the actual SQL executed when the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the `FormattableString` parameter.

It appears that when this type of string is used, Entity Framework Core tries to substitute the variables of the interpolated string, but it couldn't do that with a *parameterless* SQL string, so it failed.

I changed the parameter type to `RawSqlString` and now the insert is done.

Answer (score 0):

Could you include the part where you create: 'command' ?

Explanation: From the stack it seems like your parameters are wrongly addressed. The reader tries to pair every parameter up to create the final SQL query, but it fails at one called @p0.

Disclaimer: *I cannot yet write a comment to your question (however I know it would be the best format).*